# Safe to use the same temporary table name in parallel transactons?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, postgresql-10, temporary-tables, postgresql-11

Using postgreSQL 10 or 11, would it be safe creating temporary tables with the same name, each carrying different data? I do not intend to share the data between any sessions/connection/transactions. The name itself is not important, but I would like to safe myself the trouble of generating random names for every concurrent query that needs such intermediate table.

Temporary table is only used in different `SELECT` queries. It will be dropped at the end of each transaction with the `ON COMMIT DROP` clause.

PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-TEMPORARY) states:

> Existing **permanent** tables with the same name are not visible to the current session while the temporary table exists, unless they are referenced with schema-qualified names.

It is not clear to me if this applies to temporary tables too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

documentation means:

- if you have permanent table TABLE_A
- and you create a temporary table with the same name TABLE_A,

a permanent table will be not visible for your code.

But you could request data from the permanent table by add schema to name - **schema_name.table_name**.

Answering to your question - yes, it is safe.